Stale imu data after pause unpause cycle in unity deployed to android
Below is a minimum reproducible example.  Just create an object in a new scene and attach this script to it.  When run on an android device the object will rotate with the phone.  If you unfocus refocus, everything still works fine, but if you pause unpause the app (tapping power button on your phone and leaving it asleep for a few seconds), when the app is unpaused, the imu data seems not to update for several seconds (seems proportional to the duration of the pause which makes me think there is a buffer or something that is getting filled up).
Is there a way to fix this?  (idk how it is related, but this only happens when the device is running on battery, not when plugged in)
using UnityEngine;

public class GyroController : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void Start()
    {
        // Enable the gyroscope
        Input.gyro.enabled = true;
        Input.gyro.updateInterval = 0.02f;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        
    }
    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        // Get the gyroscope attitude (rotation)
        Quaternion gyroRotation = Input.gyro.attitude;

        // Convert the gyroscope rotation to Unity's coordinate system
        Quaternion convertedRotation = new Quaternion(gyroRotation.x, gyroRotation.y, -gyroRotation.z, -gyroRotation.w);

        // Apply the rotation to the parent object
        transform.rotation = convertedRotation;
    }
}

